# Gravity form ajax is not giving any response in BlockRevealers popup

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Gravity form is working with magnific popup, not working with this block revealer. 
I checked default form ajax and it is working in the block revealer. 
Please check the html and js code.

Block Revealer used - [Block Revealer](https://tympanus.net/Development/BlockRevealers/modal.html)

**HTML**

```
    <button id="event-rental-form-trigger" class="btn btn-primary" 
      title="Click Me">Click Me</button>

     <div id="event-rental-modal" class="modal">

       <span id="event-rental-modal-close" class="i-close event-rental-modal-close"></span>

       <div class="form-block caps">
          <h2 class="text-center pad-bottom-sm">Event Rental Request</h2>
          <?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id=1 title=false description=false ajax=true]'); ?>
       </div><!-- .form-block -->

     </div><!-- .modal -->
```

**JS**

```
if ($('#event-rental-modal').length) {
var eventRentalModalEl = document.querySelector('#event-rental-modal'),
        eventRentalModalRevealer = new RevealFx(eventRentalModalEl),
        //deleteCtrl = modalEl.querySelector('#newsletter-form-trigger'),
        eventRentalModalCloseCtrl = eventRentalModalEl.querySelector('#event-rental-modal-close');

document.querySelector('#event-rental-form-trigger').addEventListener('click', function () {
  eventRentalModalEl.classList.add('modal--open');
  $('#site-wrapper').addClass('js-overlay');
  eventRentalModalRevealer.reveal({
    bgcolor: '#393E46',
    direction: 'tb',
    duration: 400,
    easing: 'easeOutCirc',
    onCover: function (contentEl, revealerEl) {
      contentEl.style.opacity = 1;
    },
    onComplete: function () {
      eventRentalModalCloseCtrl.addEventListener('click', closeEventRentalModal);
    }
  });
});


function closeEventRentalModal(ev) {
  eventRentalModalCloseCtrl.removeEventListener('click', closeEventRentalModal);
  $('#site-wrapper').removeClass('js-overlay');
  eventRentalModalEl.classList.remove('modal--open');
  eventRentalModalRevealer.reveal({
    bgcolor: ev.target.classList.contains('event-rental-modal-close') ? '#393E46' : '#FFB823',
    direction: 'bt',
    duration: ev.target.classList.contains('even-rental-modal-close') ? 200 : 400,
    easing: 'easeOutCirc',
    onCover: function (contentEl, revealerEl) {
      contentEl.style.opacity = 0;
    },
    onComplete: function () {
      modalEl.classList.remove('modal--open');
    }
  });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a fix for this issue. The problem was this block reveal js wrap the the div with a div with class "block-revealer__content" for the animation , so the javascript by gravity form will not work..

Added some custom jquery functions and its working perfectly fine.

```
 $('.modal-trigger').on('click', function () {
   var modalID = $(this).attr('id');
   var animatingColor  = '#393E46';

   if($('.' + modalID).hasClass('tour-schedule-modal')){
     var animatingColor  = '#FFB823';
   }

   var commonModalRevealItem = document.querySelector('.' + modalID);
   var commonModalRevealer = new RevealFx(commonModalRevealItem);

   $('#popup-overlay').addClass('js-active');

   commonModalRevealer.reveal({
     bgcolor: animatingColor,
     direction: 'tb',
     duration: 300,
     easing: 'easeOutCirc',
     onCover: function (contentEl, revealerEl) {
       commonModalRevealItem.classList.add('modal--open');
       contentEl.style.opacity = 1;
     }
   });

   $('.' + modalID).find('.modal-close').on('click', function () {
     closeModal();
   });

   $('#popup-overlay').on('click', function () {
     closeModal();
   });


   function closeModal() {
     $('.modal').remove('modal--open');
     commonModalRevealer.reveal({
       bgcolor: animatingColor,
       direction: 'bt',
       duration: 300,
       easing: 'easeOutCirc',
       onCover: function (contentEl, revealerEl) {
         contentEl.style.opacity = 0;
       },
       onComplete: function () {
         commonModalRevealItem.classList.remove('modal--open');
         if ($('.' + modalID + ' .modal-inner').parent().hasClass('block-revealer__content')) {
           $('.' + modalID + ' .modal-inner').unwrap();
           $('.modal .block-revealer__element').remove();
         }
         $('#popup-overlay').removeClass('js-active');
       }
     });
   }


   var gfScript = new Function($('.' + modalID + ' script').text());
   gfScript();`

});
```

.modal-trigger - Popup open button

modalID - Button id ( related popup have the same id as class )

**Gravity form reloading code**

var gfScript = new Function($('.' + modalID + ' script').text());

gfScript();